# How could I put hex as string into byte?

Tags: python, python-2.7, hex

I am trying manually build a byte from hexadecimal:

```
>>> '\x74'
't'
>>> hex(116)
'0x74'
>>> hex(116)[1:]
'x74'
>>> '\\' + hex(116)[1:]
'\\x74'
>>>
```

Is it possible to create exactly `\x74` as byte?

Without using magic with `chr()`.

```
>>> chr(int(hex(116), 16))
't
```

Comment: What do you mean "as byte"?  There is no "byte" type in Python.  You can make a [bytearray](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bytearray) of length one, or a bytestring (i.e., non-unicode string).  If you want to do the, `chr` is not "magic"; it is the function that does what you're trying to do.

Comment: @BrenBarn as `'\x74'` which is `str`(actually byte in python2.7.)

Comment: The string you already created is `\x74`.  It just shows two backslashes because of the way it's displayed.  If you do `print('\\' + hex(116)[1:])` you'll see it has only one backslash.  But that's not "a byte"; it's a string with four characters in it.

Comment: @BrenBarn so there is no way how could I create `'\x74'` (as printable `t`) in code? the only one way to put it manually..

Comment: What do you mean by "manually"?  From what data do you want to create the character?

Comment: @BrenBarn actually from hex value of 116 (74 in hex)

Comment: @BrenBarn since 't' it is just '\x74', why I can't programmatically build '\x74'

Comment: You can, and you just did.  If you want a string that prints as `"t"`, that is the string `"t"`.  If you want a string that prints as `"\x74"`, that is the string `"\x74"`, which you can input as `r"\x74"` or `"\\x74"`.  There is no such thing as a string that prints as `"t"` but somehow secretly "is" `\x74`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do something like `'74'.decode('hex')`.

Output:

```
>>> '74'.decode('hex')
't'
```

Comment: Note: Using the "special" codecs with `str.decode`/`str.encode` is deprecated, and doesn't work in Py3. You have to use [`codecs` module methods to use binary->binary "decoding"/"encoding"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#binary-transforms).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for [`struct.pack`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.pack):

```
In [210]: import struct

In [211]: struct.pack('1B', 0x74)
Out[211]: 't'
```